# Authentication failure while creating new environment via Cloudrea Director : AWS was not able to validate provided access credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was following the below Cloudera documentation : Getting Started on Amazon Web Services (AWS)
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/director/latest/topics/director_aws_add_environment.html#aws_add_environment

In this step : Adding an Altus Director Environment on AWS (link below), I'm facing authentication problem.
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/director/latest/topics/director_aws_add_environment.html#aws_add_environment

Screen shot of adding new env : [adding new env via Coluera Director](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DnYm.png)

Problem : [invalid credentials problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2izA.png)

But I can connect to ec2 cluster via ssh with the username :"centos" and my pem file. (SSH Screen shot attached)
[SSH login to cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdZkg.png)

Screen shot of running cluster : [running cluster info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkDki.png)

Cluster info :

AMI : centos-7-pke-201907251446 - ami-00181e08e0300ee8f

My work on this issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744205/ec2-api-error-validating-access-credential

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/372

- It looks mostly due to time synchronization problem on the cluster. Since, while sending sending credentials from client side to cluster, credentials are being timestamped and when there is huge difference authentication will fail.
  And I have also do this step that time is sync (by installing ntp on cluster)
  Time is in sync : [cluster time is in sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN0Mg.png)
  I have also stopped and stopped the EC2 cluster post time sync.
- I have also provided correct EC2 region while creating new env i.e. "eu-central-1" (which is same as in then name of cluster)